# Error java.lang.AssertionError: expected: null<null> but was: java.lang.String<null> what does it mean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have this strange issue in my Junit 4.12 test code. The application uses Spring Framework 4.1.6 and Hibernate 4. When comparing two beans coming from different databases I get this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: null<null> but was: java.lang.String<null>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at my.test.TestClass.method(TestClass.java:105)
```

What does it mean? How to resolve it?

My test class runs with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and looks similar to this

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    {
        "classpath:beans-test.xml"
    }
)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestMdtTechnicalGridGeneration extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void method() {
            assertEquals(bean1.getThing(), bean2.getThing());
    }
}
```

**edit**: the bean I'm referring to is a simple POJO, you can imagine it look like the following:

```
public class Thing {
    private String thing;

    public void setThing(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    public String getThing() {
        return thing;
    }
}
```

I get them using Hibernate along the line of

```
SessionFactory mySF = (SessionFactory) applicationContext.getBean("mySessionFactory");
Query query = mySF.openSession().createQuery("FROM Thing WHERE code = '" + code + "'");
List<Thing> listThing = return query.list();
bean1 = listThing.get(0);
```

To address the *close vote*:
I'm not sure if all these details may help, the question is about the strange AssertError I get rather than how I get the beans. I can't find help here in SO nor Google.

**edit2**: to further clarify, the POJO itself is the exact same Java class, I use two hibernate mappings files. The only difference is `catalog="this"` and `catalog="that"` in the mapping. I use two different sessionfactories because data is stored in different schemas (aka catalog), same MySQL instance.

Comment: What is `bean.getThing()` returning and what does the `toString()` of this type looks like?

Comment: "What does it mean?" it means that `bean1.getThing()` is not equal to `bean2.getThing()`

Comment: Can you post your bean class ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some more digging I've discovered that the beans *are not* identical. The regular DAO sets the *string with value null* on Thing, while test data DAO sets *null* on Thing. The failing assert is

```
@Test
public void testNull() {
    assertEquals(null, "null");
}
```

I'm happy that it fails, values **are** different. The detail message is quite cryptical though.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and solved it by wrapping the values with String.valueOf(Your Value Here) e.g. String.valueOf("null")

Comment: This one helped me..!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with the 4.12 version of JUnit. [An issue was opened with JUnit on github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/976) and has now been fixed. Therefore the workaround is to downgrade to 4.11 or take the latest build of JUnit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10526056)

Comment: Is a link to the oficial issue in github. They give two solutions, 
1 - Go back to Junit 4.11.
2 - Update to the last version of JUnit that seems to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Spencer for the correction. Now the answer is better.

Comment: @Iker after switching to JUnit 4.11 the problem remains the same. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try below TestMethod

```
@Test
public void testNull() {
assertEquals(null, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34226141/2423194) to be confusing and led me to think it was some complicated difference between the way GreenDAO stores `String yourString = null` and `null", making me think I need to upgrade JUnit to version 5, but luckily I found out the true meaning of the answer, which is:

This error simply means that you are comparing `null` and the string `"null"`, which are not equal. In my case, I was storing `"null"` in GreenDAO when I meant to store `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error because I was using :

```
    @Test
fun trimRightNullIsSetToNull() {
    assertThat(trimRight(null), equalTo(nullValue()))
}
```

Removing equalTo and directly comparing them both solved the error :

```
    @Test
fun trimRightNullIsSetToNull() {
    assertThat(trimRight(null), nullValue())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Int marks = student.getMarks();
marks = null;
```

we can try `Assert.assertNull(student.getMarks());`

This worked for me.